# oracle 10g User id and password

Tags: oracle10g

Hi my name is Manish.M.Meshram
I download oracle 10g. 
i used scott tiger as userId and Password,
but it is not working.
what will be the user id and password
for oracle 10g.

Thank you

Comment: please read http://serverfault.com/faq (the section on "reputation"). This site is meant to be win-win. You get your questions answered, the people answering the questions get you feedback (=votes, comments, accepts)

Comment: ? - you need 15 rep to vote up, the OP can't do it yet (and, besides which, owing to timezone diffs and other commitments, may not have seen anything here since posting the question).

Answer (score 1):

The scott user is disabled by default. You will typically set a system password at the time of installation or database creation. If not, you could try system/change_on_install or system/manager.

Comment: Wasn't it sys/change_on_install, or have things changed since 8i?

Comment: On 8i it was system/manager and sys/change_on_install, but things have changed since then. In 10g you are asked to provide a password, but if you're running a scripted database creation one of the old defaults are often used for either account.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle 10g scott/tiger is not enabled by default. You must unlock the account during installation. I assume this can also be done later using an admin account (sys or sysdba)